# Getting completely different results on manual editing vs script

Tags: mesh, geometry, subdivision-surface, smooth

I have a mesh that I am importing and need to edit very simply as:

- Apply 10 levels of smoothing
- Apply one level of catmull-clark subdivision

When I do this by hand I see this:

[image]

Which is correct.

However if I grab the exact same mesh and run it through this script:

```py
import bpy

import argparse

# Create an ArgumentParser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Import an OBJ file, apply Subdivision and Smooth modifiers, and export the result")

# Add input and output file arguments
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", help="Input OBJ file path", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output OBJ file path", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

# Clear existing mesh objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Import the OBJ file
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=args.input)

# Select the imported object
obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

# Apply one level of Catmull-Clark subdivision
# subdivision_modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="Subdivision", type='SUBSURF')
# subdivision_modifier.levels = 1
# bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=subdivision_modifier.name)

# Apply the smooth modifier
smooth_modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="Smooth", type='SMOOTH')
smooth_modifier.factor = 10

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=smooth_modifier.name)

subdivision_modifier2 = obj.modifiers.new(name="Subdivision", type='SUBSURF')
subdivision_modifier2.levels = 2

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=subdivision_modifier2.name)

# Update the view
bpy.context.view_layer.update()

# Export the modified object as a new OBJ file
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=args.output, use_selection=True, use_materials=False)
```

I See this

[image]

I don't understand why, it's the same operations as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to:

```
smooth_modifier.factor = 10
```

Use instead

```
smooth_modifier.iterations = 10
```

As you can see below, "Factor" is "factor" in Python and "Repeat" is "iterations":

[image]